# Spring scheduler causing one issue, how to solve this?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am getting below message :

```
appears to have started a thread named [schedulerFactory_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it.
```

could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your bean definition have a destroy hook on it?  i.e.

```
<bean id="schedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" 
destroy-method="destroy">
```

Comment: no , but i have contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) method in class MoodysContextListener , which implementing ServletContextListener. could you tell me if I add destroy method ,then what should I write in that method ?

Comment: It's a method on the Quartz scheduler so you just add the attribute to the app context xml... http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#destroy().  Hmmm, maybe it's already getting invoked...I guess it's pretty easy to debug.